# Unable to unpin an app on my Lenovo tab

Tags: applications

I am using a Lenovo tab, it is pinned with Ola play app. I tried many times to unpin it by pressing back, multitasking at a time. It is showing unpinned. Again it is automatically pinning to the same app immediately. I am also unable to access Settings > Safe Mode option also.

Please tell me a solution other than factory reset option.

Comment: Can you reboot the device? Or if the battery is removable just remove it and place it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to perform a soft reset by holding the power and volume down button until the screen goes blank. If it has a removable battery, take it out and then put it back in. If neither of the above work, google soft reset lenovo tab (model)

Comment: TQ one and all ..it was solved by soft reset tq

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to unlock my OLA play tab through following steps:

1. Unpin it
2. Press "no thanks"
3. Press lock button with home key and hold both of them. It will show power off and restart options.
4. Release lock button only
5. Hold the home key and click on power off, and don't remove your finger. Keep holding it. It will ask you to run as "safe mode".
6. Click OK and release home key. It will turn on in safe mode.
7. Go to Settings, press home and deselect OLA launcher.
8. Select your tab launcher
9. Restart. It will start as a normal tab